# Howto trigger jQuery event after scrolling to certain object on page (not "if scrollTop" solution)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, scroll

I want to float a layer as soon as I am scrolling to a certain point on a page. But my page is not static in height, but (very) dynamic. So this known solution will not work for me:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 1000) { 
   // do this
}
```

That's the reason I am wondering if there is a posibility to fire an event at the very moment a certain object (e.g. a div) has appeared on my screen?

Other solutions are also welcome of course.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this answer here [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling#answer-488073)

And after you can trigger the event like this

```
$(document).trigger('elementVisible');
```

And here you can add your code

```
$(document).on('elementVisible', function (event, data) {
  //code goes here
});
```

Comment: Yes the page you suggested solved the problem, thanks!